# Angular add class to body from inside view

Tags: angularjs, html

I have an app where, when a thumbnail is clicked a modal will open and play the video connected to the thumbnail. What I need to do is add a class to the body tag when this modal is open so I can stop the body content scrolling behind the modal.

I am using an **ng-click** to activate an **ng-show** and **ng-if**. The problem is all of this is inside the scope of an **ng-repeat** which in turn is inside the **view**. I am new to Angular and any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="videos" ng-controller="modalCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li class="clear-fix" ng-repeat="video in filtered = videos | filter:search | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">


      <!-- THIS ACTIVATES THE MODAL WHEN CLICKED -->
      <div ng-click="showModal = !showModal" class="item-thumbnail float-left pointer" back-img="{{video.thumbnail}}">
      </div>


      <div class="item-details-container float-left">
        <div class="item-header">
          <div ng-click="showModal = !showModal" class="item-title pointer">
            <h3 class="underline">{{video.title}}</h3>
          </div>

          <div class="item-author pointer">
            <span>by: <a class="underline" ui-sref="{{video.author_link}}">{{video.author}}</a></span>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item-description">
          <p>{{video.description.trunc(150)}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>



      <!-- THIS IS THE MODAL BACKGROUND COVER -->
      <div ng-show="showModal" class="modal-cover"></div>



      <!-- THIS IS THE MODAL -->
      <div ng-show="showModal" class="modal-container">
        <div ng-if="showModal" class="video-modal clear-fix">
          <button class="btn-close" ng-click="$parent.showModal = false">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </button>

          <div class="video-container float-left">
            <youtube-video video-url="video.url"></youtube-video>
          </div>

          <div class="video-info-container float-right">
            <div class="video-info">
              <div class="item-header">
                <div class="item-title">
                  <h3>{{video.title}}</h3>
                </div>

                <div class="item-author pointer">
                  <span>by: <a class="underline" ui-sref="{{video.author_link}}">{{video.author}}</a></span>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="item-description">
                <p>{{video.description}}</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="voting-container clear-fix">
              <div class="votingButton btn-solid pointer" ng-click="upVote(video); showDetails = !showDetails">
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="bugButton btn-solid pointer">
                <i class="fa fa-flag-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </div>
              <div ng-show="showDetails = showDetails"><span>Thank you for voting.</span></div>       
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: **Why** do you need to add a class to the body - which is outside of your app?

Comment: On a mobile screen the modal content will need to scroll. To prevent two scroll bars appearing I need to set the body overflow to hidden when the modal is open. The body is outside of the view, not the app and the main controller.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are looking for [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive.

So if you would add this to the body element you want to disable scrolling on, it would give you what you are looking for:

```
<div ng-class="{'is-modal-open': showModal}">
```

In short, this will add the class `is-modal-open` when `showModal` validates to `true`

Just to clarify (Thanks @Ronnie), you need to make sure the `<div>` that contains what you call `body` is inside the scope of your controller (somewhere inside the div that has `ng-controller`). And you shouldn't put it directly on the `<body>` tag

[edit]
I don't like using `$rootScope`, but you could try this:

```
<body ng-class="{'is-modal-open': showModal}">

// Your div
<div ng-click="showHideModal()" class="item-title pointer">

// your controller
app.controller('modalCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.showHideModal = function() {
        $rootScope.showModal = !$rootScope.showModal;
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I think the issue is the body tag is out of scope of his controller

Comment: I hope he isn't trying to add that class directly on the body tag, but i'll add a clarification

Comment: Yes I need to add a class to the body tag which is outside of the scope of the ng-repeat and the view.

Comment: Its nasty and I don't like it, but you could update $rootScope instead. I edited my answer

Comment: This worked perfectly AlexD thank you. Can you tell me why this is a bad way to do it. Will this cause me other issues?

Comment: Its generally bad practice putting stuff on the `rootScope`, its uncontrolled and it will travel with you through the entire application. A better way to do this would be to use controller inheritance. You can search about it online, plenty guides and documentation about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do :

You can use ng-class in your body tag like this

```
<body ng-class="{'is-modal-open': freeze}">
```

And you can write ng-click on your thumbnail like this

```
<div class="thumbnail" ng-click="is-modal-open=true"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just make a div in your template like this:

```
<div class="fullscreen-modal">
//content here
</div>
```

And in your controller you could do this:

```
var elementResult = element[0].getElementsByClassName('fullscreen-modal');
angular.element(document.body).append(element);
```

Now your element is a direct child of `<body>`.

**OR**

Define the modal div outside of ng-repeat.

Then define a scope function

```
$scope.openModal() = function(contentOrVideoId) 
    {
        //put logic here
        $scope.showModal = true;
        $scope.modalContent = contentOrVideoId;
    }
```

And just call this function inside ng-repeat with `ng-click="openModal('IdOrContent')"`

Comment: I will try this but considering the modal is inside an ng-repeat, would this method not append a modal for every element inside the ng-repeta?

Comment: if you select the element by class name this might be the case. but you could make a dynamic classname like class="modal-no-{{key}}" ... I mean a better way would be to make a directive for the modal.

Comment: Or you could just define the modal-div outside the ng-repeat and then call a function which takes care about the logic.